# Matching an int as a string in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a variable called server in jinja2 which can either be a number or string, however when I try to match when its a number (eg 1) it throws an error; I tried converting to a string but cannot find the function?

```
{% set server = 1 %}
{% if 'none' in exp(server) %}
no server
{% endif %}
```

is this possible? thanks! 
Ahdee

Answer (score 0):

found an answer! 
cast to string.

```
{% set server = 1 %}
{% if 'none' in server|string %}
no server
{% endif %}
```